# how to load dynamically generated table data into form inside modal?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I have a table which is dynamically generated. the table looks like:-

```
    <table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" 
    cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>S.N</th>
        <th>Branch Name</th>
        <th>Branch Location</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>S.N</th>
        <th>Branch Name</th>
        <th>Branch Location</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:Each="b,iter : ${branches}">
        <td th:text="${iter.index}+1"></td>
        <td th:text="${b.branchName}"></td>
        <td th:text="${b.branchLocation}"></td>
        <td th:text="${b.status}"></td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">
            <button  class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#branchModal">Edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning">Deactivate</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and i have bootstrap modal. now when i click edit button of the table i want to load the clicked table row data inside the form of modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="branchModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="branch-name" class="col-form-label">Branch Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="branch-location" class="col-form-label">Branch Location:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="branch-location"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button style="margin-right:10px;" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

how can i achieve it ?

note:- i am not using jquery so solution with plain javascript will be appreciated.

Comment: You can add the id of the row (like this: `<button data-id="10">Edit</button>`) and, get data by on click the button using `ajax` and put it into the modal !!

Comment: do you have a sample code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a function `loadDataOnModal` to handle displaying your modal, add this to your edit button:

`th:onclick="| loadDataOnModal('${b.branchName}', '${b.branchLocation}')|"`

I see you only need branch name & location in your modal body.

Comment: button is like this:- <button th:onclick="loadDataOnModal()" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#branchModal">Edit</button> i am not sure what happens inside th:onclick on your code.

Comment: I changed the answer to match your function name. I'm passing the branchName & branchLocation to loadDataOnModal so you don't have to fetch it again.

Comment: the code you provided worked like a charm. thank you. i never saw something like this on thymeleaf. it's new and elegant solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Hi simply run this code on the click event that opens your modal for each value you wish to change:

```
document.getElementById('recipient-name').value = 'Value you wish to set'
```

You can also access the value of the element you are clicking by passing in the event variable like so:

```
document.getElementById('clicked').addEventListener('click', event => {
  document.getElementById('recipient-name').value = event.target.value
})
```

This is basic concept you can take it further from there...

Hope this helps